# Porting html template into UmbracoCMS

Tags: html, templates, umbraco, porting, migrate

I am given a html template (with css3 and js), the template is kinda big (about 20 html pages).

I need to port the template into Umbraco and cant find a way to do that.I have managed to create a document type with the index.html template, but I don't know how to add the rest of the html files and link them all together.

Comment: You've got a fair amount of learning to do then. Suggest you buy a subscription to umbraco TV (19 euros) to learn the basics.

Comment: I cant afford the Umbraco TV for now, is there any other source that can teach me how to do just that? i dont even need to be able to manage the content, just import the html into the UmbracoCMS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, http://umbraco.com/developers-site.aspx forum and documentation.
The forum is very friendly but you won't always get instant answers.
Learn how to install umbraco and stat with one of the starte kits which is a simple example of site build in umbraco. 
Quite a steep learning curve but really worth it.